# How to change themes in Anchor CMS?

Tags: php, html, css, themes, anchor-cms

Say I have two themes in themes folder, `default` and `custom`. I know I can switch my current theme to be `custom` by renaming the folder to `default` and the original `default` folder to something other than `default`.

But is there a way to actually configure somewhere in the config file or admin menu? I tried looking in their [documentation](http://anchorcms.com/docs/theming/custom-templates) which basically talks about creating themes but not switching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Admin panel` > `Extend` > `Site MetaData`

At the bottom of the page, there is a dropdown menu to switch themes under `Apperance`. Yes, with a spelling error. :)

[image]

Comment: It appers that they have corrected the spelling error.